# multithreading dilemma

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is the code.
plan is to ping all hosts in a range and get fqdn back...which is working, but takes a loooong time....so thinking about multiprocessing...but cant get it to work. The code just hangs at the p.map(...) and not goes beyond that.
could someone please assist?.............hope the code is readable..

```
import subprocess
import os
import socket
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from datetime import datetime



range_85 = "10.85.40"
range_87 = "10.87.40"

print ("starting")

replyfile = open("pingdns_replies.txt", "a")
#replyfile.write("START %s \n" % datetime.now())

print("file opened")


def ping(host):
        print ("entered function")
        #for ip in range (50,250):
                #host = range_85 +"."+ str(ip)
        print (host)
        rep = subprocess.call("ping %s" % host, shell=False)
        if rep == 0:   
                try:
                        dns = socket.getfqdn(host)
                except:
                        dns = " "
                        print ("%s at %s is up" % (dns, host))
                        replyfile.write(" %s at %s is up \n" % (dns, host))
        else:
                try:
                        dns = socket.getfqdn(host)
                        print("%s at %s is down ?" % (dns, host))
                        replyfile.write(" %s at %s is down ? \n" % (dns,host))
                except:
                        dns = " "
                        print ("%s received no reply" % host)
                        replyfile.write(" %s received no reply \n" % (dns, host))

#ips = (range_85 + "." + str(i) for i in range(0,255))

ips = []
for i in range(1,255):
        ips.append(range_85+'.'+str(i))


print ("ips created")
print (ips)


with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as p:        
        p.map(ping, ips)

replyfile.write("END %s \n" % datetime.now())
replyfile.close()
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it readable.

Comment: You don't need multiprocessing if you're invoking `ping` as a subprocess; you're already using multiple processes.

Comment: @Daniel....it takes an hour to ping the whole range....is there any way to make it go faster by spawning multiple processes to handle it?...introducing multiprocessing just hangs at that point and doesn't even get to the def ping(host)

Answer (score 0):

this code is incomplete so it's hard to know for sure,
but it seems you are trying to create a list of ips to scan in this line:

```
ips = range_85 +"."+ str('%d' % i for i in range(1,254))
```

the problem is with the str() conversion, you are converting a generator object into a string and not actually generating a string from each element of the generator

to create a generator for your ip range you can replace that line with something like:

```
ips = ( range_85 + "." + str(i) for i in range(1,254))
```

i should note that you are excluding 0 and 254 from your ip range which are still valid in your ip range (even if you dont want to ping 10.85.40.255) range(0,255) would give you the whole ip range (exluding 255)

**edit**

given that the question changed completely here's the answer to the new question:

your call to ping never returns, at least on linux "ping xx.xx.xx.xx" will send icmp packets indefinitely until it is stopped by a SIGINT

you can refer to the doc of ping here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping

try changing the line

```
rep = subprocess.call("ping 1 %s" % host, shell=False)
```

to

```
rep = subprocess.call("ping -c 1 %s" % host, shell=False)
```

note that you could and should send more than one packet if you want to make sure random packet drops won't affect the outcome.

also it seems like you only use a thread pool of 2 threads and unless you're unbelievably starved for resources you could use a lot more than that (probably in the hundreds if you're using a normal PC) since the ping command doesn't require a lot of cpu power and it just mostly hangs waiting for an answer.

one final note: you're writing from multiple locations to the same file, i'd  advise against that and instead use either a mutex around the file call or use the multiprocessing thread safe containers to save the results then write them from the main thread to the file once everything is finished

Comment: ))

#ips = (range_85 + "." + str(i) for i in range(0,255))

ips = []
for i in range(1,255):
        ips.append(range_85+'.'+str(i))
        
generating the range like this for now, and it goes to this multi code but but call to a function not working,                                                          
 with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as p:        
        p.map(ping, ips)

Comment: @ramzal please learn to format, otherwise it is impossible to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: thats what i am trying to figure out..sadly no luck yet.

Comment: @Chris...reposted the question, formatted this time.